# Attach vectors to each datapoint

Tags: matlab, plot, visualize

I am having some problems visualizing my data..

It consist of matrix with 3 columns [x y z] each respresenting the position of a datapoint.  I have to draw 3 vectors for each data point,

These are stored in same manner as the data.
How do i plot the three vectors for each data point?
prefferably in plot3.

Comment: Why not use multiple [`quiver3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html?refresh=true) objects?

Comment: My datapoints are plotted using plot3.. it would be neat to append the vector onto the my original plot

Comment: You can... Just do `plot3(data); hold on; quiver3(otherdata);`

Comment: Seem to do it :).. 

I merged a bit of this  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28608-plot-unit-vectors/content/fcn_plotUnitVectors.m

And yours to make it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by @Suever and the use of this [implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28608-plot-unit-vectors/content/fcn_plotUnitVectors.m) seemed to resolve my issue.